# Why does the first example work but the second doesn't?

Tags: batch-file

Example 1:

```
@echo off
cd G:\Games\Console\ROMS\MAME\Games\1P\1P Breakout\
for %%f in (*.zip) do echo %%~nf
```

Example 2:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (G:\Games\Console\ROMS\MAME\Games\1P\1P Breakout\*.zip) do echo %%~nf
```

Comment: Try quoting the path, since it has spaces: `"G:\Games\Console\ROMS\MAME\Games\1P\1P Breakout\*.zip"`

Comment: Yes, the command `CD` is an exception in that it does not treat spaces as delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the parentheses in a `for` loop is a space-delimited set, which supports wildcards.  In your first example, the wildcard expression `(*.zip)` expands to give the set `(a.zip b.zip c.zip ...)` and the `for` loop iterates over that set.

In your second example, the elements in your set: `G:\Games\Console\ROMS\MAME\Games\1P\1P` and `Breakout\*.zip`.  Presumably, this gives a one-element set, because the wildcards in `Breakout\*.zip` probably expands to the empty set.

To fix the problem, you need to add quotes:

```
for %%f in ("G:\Games\Console\ROMS\MAME\Games\1P\1P Breakout\*.zip") do echo %%~nf
```

Note that in general, you need to add quotes around file paths with spaces in batch.  One of the very few exceptions is the `CD` command, which does not treat spaces as delimiters, so the fact that your first example works is sort of an accident.